# "A type cannot be introduced in a function parameter list"

Tags: c++, class, parameters, bulletphysics

I'm using the Bullet physics library in a C++ program on Visual Studio. When I turn off the Visual Studio language extensions I cannot get the Bullet physics library to compile, I get the error:

> 'btSerializer': a type cannot be introduced in a function parameter
>   list

And brings me to the line:

```
virtual const char* serialize(void* dataBuffer, class btSerializer* serializer) const;
```

The documentation for these functions are here:

[Documentation](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCollisionObject.html#a6d0f9602bd4a06f20ceeec3a7e18d552)

Edit: Verifiable example, what is happening here?

```
class Bar
{public:
    void serialize(void* dataBuffer, class btSerializer* serializer) ;
};

int main()
{

}
```

If Visual Studio language extensions are on, it compiles fine. If I turn it off it emits the same error as I mentioned above. Also, if I eliminate the first argument of the void pointer, so that the function has only the btSerializer* argument it compiles fine. So for example:

```
class Bar
{public:
    void serialize(void* dataBuffer, class btSerializer* serializer) ;
};
```

Emits the error:

> 'btSerializer': a type cannot be introduced in a function parameter
>   list

But:

```
class Bar
{public:
    void serialize(class btSerializer* serializer) ;
};
```

Compiles fine.

Also, a forward declaration of class btSerializer; makes the error go away.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `class` keyword as in `virtual void serializeSingleObject(btSerializer* serializer) const;`

Comment: [mcve] please. I can't reproduce it. So I have no way to know if it's a compiler bug or my attempt is wrong.

Comment: @Dr Yunke, I tried, same thing. I'm trying to make verifiable example but each header depends on many other headers and I'm having trouble.

Comment: You need `class btSerializer` declared (possibly forward-declared) before you can mention it in a function parameter.

Comment: @n.m. - No you don't. Not with an elaborated type specifier anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeler yes you do.

Comment: @PasserBy - Disallowed by what? Because neither Clang nor GCC verify that, nor can I find a relevant piece in the standard at the moment. So other than agreeing with a possibly faulty error, what are you basing that claim on?

Comment: @n.m. - Citation required. I couldn't find one.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry you are right, I was thinking of some other rule.

Comment: Well I'm sorry I'm not able to provide a verifiable example as each header seems to include about 5 other headers, and there's too much code. Could I ask though, many of these functions go along the lines of void func(struct Foo* p); and int func(class Foo* p);  I'm just wondering, what does this specific "class" or "struct" keyword actually do in the function signature? I didn't know in C++ it was necessary or common.

Comment: A forward declaration of btSerializer gets rid of the error message.

Comment: @StoryTeller. I think I might have something like a verifiable example of what's happening.

Comment: @Zebrafish it does look like a compiler bug.

Comment: Yup, I concur. Neither Clang nor GCC choke on either example. And VC++'s erratic behavior further supports it as being a bug.